# EPS sizing for lunar mission

Tags: the-moon, solar-power, power, lunar-gateway

As part of a university project, I am working on EPS sizing for a mission to the lunar environment. I have sized the SA and batteries, chosen the components and the PDCU; however, having never been in this role before, I would like to understand if anything else needs to be done in order for a phase A project to be considered completed. I would also like to know if I can add anything to further enrich the work done so far.

Comment: You need to expand your acronyms, and give us some detail on how you approached the first part of the problem.

Comment: you're going to university for this!  get the answer there!  tell us the answer

Comment: *Welcome to Stack Exchange!* What is an EPS and an SA? It's best to write out your acronyms the first time they are used so that readers like me will understand the question. *Thanks!*

Comment: At a top level, you 've done exactly what you need to do.  However, have you properly accounted for all the assumptions to compute SA and battery array size?  Are you planning to survive lunar night, and all its thermal implications? Have you taken into account shading on the solar panels by terrain or vehicle appendages?  Are you doing just a constant/average power budget, or a full energy balance budget?

Comment: Welcome to SpaceExploration Stack Exchange!
We nerds might have answers to some things, but you might actually be better placed to answer your own questions using help from the resources afforded to you as a student!
Thanks' for posting though, if someone has the answer I'm sure they'll let you know.
I agree with @uhoh, EPS, SA need to be expanded. We might have a better idea what your question relates to, and thus where we might source and answer from, if you were to do so.